# Can Ion-Dipole Force Occur Between Lecithin and Water?

Tags: intermolecular-forces

So, ion-dipole force occurs between an ion and a polar molecule. I would like to ask if an ion-dipole force would occur between water molecules and lecithin as seen in the picture, since it has a negatively charged oxygen atom on the phosphate group and a positively charged nitrogen atom on the choline group?

Would the attraction between them be considered an ion-dipole force, or is it only applicable between a lone ion and a polar molecule? I understand it seems like a simple question, however, all examples and explanations I've found just stop there.

[image: Lecithin]

Comment: It can be reduced to the physical scenario of the + charge, the - charge and the dipole as 2 adjacent opposite charges. Each of them interact with each.